# Why is information that narrows it down deliberately removed from a question closed as "too broad"?

Tags: discussion

This question recently was closed as "too broad": https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/138290/homepage-is-loading-very-slow-while-internal-pages-are-faster.

As it was originally written, it was clearly too broad, so closing as "Too broad" was IMHO a correct call.

However, after it was closed, the OP added the following information to the body:

> EDIT: I found what causes this slowness: it was a views block (visualization of ~5500 nodes). That block was visible only at homepage. After setting the views cache on views settings page, it's OK now.

Now, IMHO, that was a sensible edit.  It added relevant information that narrowed down the question. The question can now be answered (Answer: You need to fix the views cache settings.) This could even have been added as a self-answer if the question had been re-opened).  I consider the edit made by the OP helpful (e.g. if somebody were googling for "slow drupal" and found the edited version of the question, they would learn that a bad views cache could be a possible cause of the slowness).

However, the diamond mod decision here was *not* to reopen, but instead to roll back the question in order to make sure the question stayed too broad to be un-answerable.

I just wonder: What is the rationale behind deliverately removing information that is added to the question by the OP in order to make a "too broad" question answerable? Are such removals of information aligned with the best-practices of the community?

Answer (score 2):

That edit was an answer: The cause of slowness was the view used for the front page, and setting the cache fixed the problem. If then the OP wanted to know why the view slowed down the page, that is a different question which we could not probably answer without being too generic or giving a broad answer.

The question is too broad, since it is not giving the necessary information to answer it (versus guessing what caused the problem).

Generally speaking, adding more details to the question is allowed, but not adding an answer to the question. In this case, the extra information would have been "the front page contains a block showing about 550 nodes created with the Views module"; at that point, the OP should have understood why the front page is so slow to load, while other pages are not. What an answer could just suggest is enabling the cache for that view so that the Views module would not execute the same SQL query every time the front page is shown.

Comment: To me, it looks like a "Catch-22": The question is closed, so it can't be answered. The OP adds information to narrow it down, get it re-opened, and then type in the edit as a self-answer.  To prevent it from being re-opened and answered properly, the edit is deleted.

Comment: I'm not sure how this question is going to be a useful addition to the knowledge repository here @FreeRadical...the OP says "There's nothing special on the homepage", while the edit says there's a visualisation of 5500 nodes on the home page. Hardly "nothing special". This realisation could only help somebody else who also had a visualisation of 5500 nodes on the homepage that they'd forgotten about. I think that's quite an unlikely scenario

Comment: @Clive, I am asking about best practices, not this particular instance. If one determines a question too localized to be helpful to others,  isn't best practice to close as: Resolved in a manner unlikely to help others, rather than too broad.

Comment: Yes I think that would be a valid close reason. Too broad is also appropriate in my opinion, as once you remove the answer from the question, there's not enough detail for it to be answerable. I'm not sure there's a best practice here, such things depend on the individual question too much. It's quite common for multiple close reasons to potentially apply to a single question

Comment: @Clive I guess the next time we will read "the front page is not doing anything special; I just have a module that parses 100 pages from external sites to grab information from dynamically created pages returning HTML markup." `;)`

Comment: @FreeRadical I cant agree with *"To prevent it from being re-opened"* part of your first comment. It was deleted to prevent answer in question, not to prevent reopening. With answer already in comment, it is no point in keeping question open anyway, right? Sad situation, but nothing better to do than what was done :( For what it's worth, voted to reopen **but** your edit invalidates already posted answer, and that's a **very bad thing** to happen.

Answer (score 0):

This question is about what to do in the case where a question is correctly closed as "too broad", and the OP then updates the question by adding the answer to the question

Having the answer in the question is depreciated, so this is not an ideal situation, so what is the "best" response?

The alternatives are:

1. Deleting the edit by rolling the question back to the previous version.
2. Do nothing (i.e. leave the edit, and also leave it closed as "too broad").
3. Reword the answer into a pseudo-question, so that the it not "too broad", nor are there an answer in the question (i.e one *rewords* the question "to fit the rules in the help center").

Of these three, the first IMHO is the least desirable option.  The question is now worthless, as there is no information visible to help anyone, nor can any such information be added since it is closed.  Exercising this option gains nothing and results in a closed question that will stay around as noise until somebody deletes it.

The second option is slightly better.  I understand that closed questions are purged after some time.  However, with this option the solution remains visible until that happens. I have problem understanding what is gained by *deleting* possible information, just to satisfy some arbitrary "rule".  The usefulness of the edit may indeed be contested, but IMHO keeping information visible for some time is *always* better than hiding it *immediately*.  I would go for this option if the value of the edited-in answer is very low.  It gives the issue some exposure, and while it is exposed, interested parties can discuss on meta whether to salvage or not.

The third option, in particular if the information in the edit is useful (YMMV), is my choice for "best practice".  While far from ideal, this is the best choice in a bad situation.  This option makes re-opening *possible*, and after re-opening, the answer can be added as a self-answer, and the pseudo-answer can be removed from the question, thereby turning the question/answer combo into something that follows the protocol outlined in the help-center.

(And for the record: I think the edited-in information in this case was useful. I've actually been bitten by this problem. Everybody can't be a cache boffin. But, as I said, YMMV.)

Comment: I strongly disagree with 3rd option. Answers in questions are discouraged for many reasons, and one of them is - closed unanswered questions are purged after some time. So option you say is the best is actually exactly what you want avoid - deleting content. Just with a bit postponed sentence.

Comment: I wasn't aware of the auto-purge misfeature.  In that case, I swap the my two last options.  (So you now strongly disagree with the 2nd option.)

Answer (score 0):

I strongly oppose answers in questions for many reasons:

1. Pretty stiff rules of quality is what made me to come here and stay in the first place.
2. Unanswered, unupvoted, closed questions ar sometimes purged, and keeping answer in question makes it count as unanswered - so it is just a way to delete content, even **more** than rollback is. After rollback, answer is still visible in post's revision history, and if it gets reopened, anyone can take it from there and post. If answer is in question, there is no way to have it reopened, and soon only 10k users can see it, and that only if they have link.
3. By letting people know it is OK to answer in question, how can we make it clear enough it applies only to closed ones? I believe we can't, so it should be discouraged altogether.

If question can have useful answer, it should be edited into shape, and reopened. That's the only way to keep quality, and to keep content from being deleted. And if that edit would invalidate already-posted answers, it shouldn't happen. Nor answer-in-question should. New Q&A pair is the way to go then.

Comment: "And if that edit would invalidate already-posted answers, it shouldn't happen."  In this case, the already-posted answer by *Pravin Ajaaz* was *invalid* even before the OP edited.  His answer was just generic advice on tuning a Drupal site, *ignoring* the fact that the OP said the problem just affected a single page.  However, the powerpoint linked to by *mikeytown2* in a comment (also posted *before* the edit) was pretty good.  It discusses how to tune caching to boost performance.

Comment: @FreeRadical I believe his answer was as valid as possible for a question as broad as it was. OP said, clearly, that this one page is in no important way different than others, after all. Answer just respected that claim. If anything, it was **our fault** not to close self-contradictory question soon enough.

Comment: If a question is too broad, it tends to attract "shot-in-the-dark" answers.  We certainly don't want chamelon questions, but if we take the "an edit shouldn't invalidate an existing answer"-rule too far, it will make it impossible to edit-in new information to narrow it down if the too broad question already has an answer.  Do we really want to insist that a new Q&A pair is posted to get around this "rule".

Comment: @FreeRadical not to simply keep rule obeyed, no. To avoid downvotes on answer that someone put his effort into, on answer that was OK, with the only "fault" it assumed false information in question was true? Yes, definitely we should avoid that. If we was too late to avoid that by putting question on fold before answer was posted, then sadly we have only bad choices - but hurting innocent answerer is the very worst of them for me.